# Microsoft Word PDF figures appear blurry when loading document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

In Microsoft Word for Mac (v. 16.28), PDF figures appear blurry/low quality in the editor when I'm loading a previously saved document. They look almost like raster images scaled to fit. Figures appear fine when initially inserted. My current workaround is to right click the figure and select `Change Picture`, and reselect the figure PDF file. The figure is then reinserted and appears fine. Strangely, this only happens to certain figures in the document, not all of them. All PDFs are exported from Adobe Illustrator, using the same export settings.

Is there a way to make sure PDF figures are always displayed properly in the editor, without reinserting them?

Comment: How exactly are you inserting the PDFs in Word?

Comment: Hi, `Insert`->`Pictures`->`Picture from File ...`